# How to create list in iOS using Swift language?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in iOS development and I don't know how to create list view in iOS application development using Swift language?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Create a new application in Xcode from the "Master-Detail Application" template and you'll get full working sample code for free! - Then read the ["Table View Programming Guide for iOS"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html). The sample code in this guide is still Objective-C, but the online documentation has both the Swift and Objective-C methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UITableView` that functions same as List View in Android

Comment: Thanks Idrees Ashraf . I also want to know that if we don't know the size of list and items are adding on run time.Then how it will be perform ?

Comment: You can use NSMutableArray to add the items on run time and can reload UITableView to update the size. Here is a good tutorial that will help you to achieve what you are looking for: http://www.codingexplorer.com/getting-started-uitableview-swift/

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer so it can help others.

Comment: Thanks, its really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

UITableView is the best option to do so.
If you don,t know the size of the list, you should use Array of swift.
As you get the contents in array , reload the tableView. using table.reload() method.

Answer (score 1):

Try UITableView ...  For example visit here [**How to create / make a simple tableview in iOS8 and swift**](http://www.jogendra.com/2014/11/how-to-create-make-simple-tableview-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITableView` to generate list.

For more information you can check Apple's site : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/